# Using background images for UITableViewCells (grouped style) - corners not rounded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a grouped style tableview which features cells with a background image. Both the tableview and the cells have been set up in Interface Builder.

Everything works, however the cells won't clip the background images corners, leaving the cell square. I've tried to enable "clip subviews", I've tried adding an UIImageView as a subview (as opposed to making the background view an imageview), I've both tried selecting a background image directly or connecting a seperate UIImageView to the cell's backroundView Outlet - to no avail.

I've tried setting up the cell programmatically, too - doesn't work. It seems the only thing that will leave the corners rounded is selecting a background color (not an image) directly in Interface Builder, which is not what I want.

There are other questions on SO with related problems, none of which covered the use of background images however, so no help there.

Thanks alot for any insights..!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `_table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` ?

FIXED: _cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

Comment: how about _cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];

Comment: !! WORKS !! Thanks dude, after spending like 32479 hours for nothing, you saved my day!! Please inlcude the solution in your answer so it's more easy to find for others with the same problem! Thanks again!!

Comment: One thing to note - image wouldn't get stretched. So before applying image as a background patter, try to resize it to height of a cell.

Answer (score 2):

The above did not work for me.

first set the background of your window to the color you want in your app delegate like this:

```
UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_background.png"]];
[self.window addSubview:bgView];
[bgView release];
```

Now if you just have one view controller just set its background to clear and your done.  I had to to the next steps because I was popping a modal window with a table view and if the background of that view was clear it looked choppy coming up.  So the code below fixed the choppy view and I still get the rounded corners because after the view has appeared I set the background to clear again and let the background from the window show through.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_background.png"]];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```